# TensorFlow 1.15: Protobuf UTF-8 Error with Large Dataset When Saving Model

Tags: protocol-buffers, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow1.15

I am experiencing a protobuf-related error in TensorFlow 1.15 when attempting to save my model using `tf.train.Saver()` with a large dataset. The same process works fine with a smaller subset of the dataset. Both subsets are sampled from a 20GB dataset, and I am confident that the data processing flow is correct.

#### Error Message:

```
libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:581] String field 'tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim.name' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_time_series_deconfounder.py", line 67, in <module>
    test_time_series_deconfounder(dataset=dataset, num_substitute_confounders=args.num_substitute_hidden_confounders,
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/Conformity_Casual_Inferance/time_series_deconfounder.py", line 370, in test_time_series_deconfounder
    rmse_without_confounders = train_rmsn(dataset_map, 'rmsn_' + str(exp_name), b_use_predicted_confounders=False)
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/Conformity_Casual_Inferance/time_series_deconfounder.py", line 201, in train_rmsn
    rnn_fit(dataset_map=dataset_map, networks_to_train='propensity_networks', MODEL_ROOT=MODEL_ROOT,
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/Conformity_Casual_Inferance/rmsn/script_rnn_fit.py", line 162, in rnn_fit
    hyperparam_opt = train(net_name, expt_name,
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/Conformity_Casual_Inferance/rmsn/core_routines.py", line 219, in train
    helpers.save_network(sess, model_folder, cp_name, optimisation_summary)
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/Conformity_Casual_Inferance/rmsn/libs/net_helpers.py", line 148, in save_network
    save_path = saver.save(tf_session, os.path.join(model_folder, "{0}.ckpt".format(cp_name)))
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/casual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1200, in save
    self.export_meta_graph(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/casual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1246, in export_meta_graph
    graph_def=ops.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(add_shapes=True),
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/casual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3238, in as_graph_def
    result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/casual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3166, in _as_graph_def
    graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'
```

The error occurs during the model-saving step, and it seems to be related to how protobuf handles certain data. I came across a similar issue described in another post, where the user faced the same error. The traceback points to `graph.ParseFromString` in TensorFlow’s internal operations.

##### Additional Observations:

- The error suggests that 'invalid UTF-8 data' was sent to protobuf.
- The issue is reproducible only with a larger subset (2.5GB) of the data, not with a smaller subset (1.5GB).
- Before the execution of `graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))`, it was confirmed that `data` is of type `<class 'bytes'>`.
- I have tried the approaches mentioned in the similar post without success.

##### Environment:

- TensorFlow version: 1.15
- Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can offer any advice on why this error might be occurring with larger datasets in TensorFlow 1.15? Any thoughts or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to assume you need to use a 3-year old version of Tensorflow for a reason but you're likely (and reasonably) going to receive responses that recommend upgrading to a recent version. Are you able to determine a reliable subset failure size? Is it possible that it's not the size of the subset that's triggering the issue but the content of the subset?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am considering upgrading TensorFlow. However, it's puzzling that this issue occurs with larger subsets from different datasets, processed and saved in the same way.@DazWilkin

Comment: Indeed. I wonder though whether the issue is the size of the dataset or the content of the dataset? It may be that your larger dataset isn't the issue but that it contains some data that is problematic.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, I will check again.@DazWilkin